# how can I use "shadow call stack" feature of clang-8 in x86_64?

Tags: c, assembly, clang, x86-64, callstack

Recently, I'm trying to test the "shadow call stack" feature of clang-8 in x86_64. But when I run the "shadowed" program, it keeps throwing out segmentation fault even if it's a "Hello_World" program.
My compiling command is "clang-8 -fsanitize=shadow-call-stack normal.c".
"normal.c" is just a simple hello_world c program:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    printf("Hello World!\n");
    return 0;
}
```

The assembler codes for main function are here:

```
   0x0000000000401130 <+0>: mov    (%rsp),%r10
   0x0000000000401134 <+4>: xor    %r11,%r11
   0x0000000000401137 <+7>: addq   $0x8,%gs:(%r11)
   0x000000000040113c <+12>:    mov    %gs:(%r11),%r11
   0x0000000000401140 <+16>:    mov    %r10,%gs:(%r11)
   0x0000000000401144 <+20>:    push   %rbp
   0x0000000000401145 <+21>:    mov    %rsp,%rbp
   0x0000000000401148 <+24>:    sub    $0x20,%rsp
   0x000000000040114c <+28>:    movl   $0x0,-0x4(%rbp)
   0x0000000000401153 <+35>:    mov    %edi,-0x8(%rbp)
   0x0000000000401156 <+38>:    mov    %rsi,-0x10(%rbp)
   0x000000000040115a <+42>:    movabs $0x402004,%rdi
   0x0000000000401164 <+52>:    mov    $0x0,%al
   0x0000000000401166 <+54>:    callq  0x401030 <printf@plt>
   0x000000000040116b <+59>:    xor    %ecx,%ecx
   0x000000000040116d <+61>:    mov    %eax,-0x14(%rbp)
   0x0000000000401170 <+64>:    mov    %ecx,%eax
   0x0000000000401172 <+66>:    add    $0x20,%rsp
   0x0000000000401176 <+70>:    pop    %rbp
   0x0000000000401177 <+71>:    xor    %r11,%r11
   0x000000000040117a <+74>:    mov    %gs:(%r11),%r10
   0x000000000040117e <+78>:    mov    %gs:(%r10),%r10
   0x0000000000401182 <+82>:    subq   $0x8,%gs:(%r11)
   0x0000000000401187 <+87>:    cmp    %r10,(%rsp)
   0x000000000040118b <+91>:    jne    0x401192 <main+98>
   0x0000000000401191 <+97>:    retq   
   0x0000000000401192 <+98>:    ud2
```

When I run this program, it throws:

```
Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0x0000000000401137 in main ()
```

In [clang-8 documentation](https://releases.llvm.org/8.0.0/tools/clang/docs/ShadowCallStack.html), it identifies this feature makes use of x86's gs register. But the actual run shows there is some issue. Is it the problem of gs register? Can anyone help me? Thanks in advance.

Comment: The documentation seems to say it’s only supported on AARCH64 in the later versions so it might be there was something wrong on x86 earlier

Comment: I notices that this feature has performance and security issues in x64. But I think in my situation this feature can not even work. My target is to test it in x64. So I'm still trying to enable it.

Answer (score 5):

The problem is, that the *runtime environment* has to initialize the `gs` register to point to a location, where the shadow call stack can be stored. This is not said very explicitly, but can be derived from [the Clang documentation](https://releases.llvm.org/7.0.1/tools/clang/docs/ShadowCallStack.html):

> ShadowCallStack currently only supports x86_64 and aarch64. A runtime is not currently provided in compiler-rt so one must be provided by the compiled application.

With the standard runtime, the `gs` register points nowhere, so the write access fails with a segmentation fault. Android libc provides such a runtime.

However, the shadow call stack feature is considered not only inefficient, but also insecure on x86_64 and it was removed in later versions. You should think carefully if you really want to use this feature. If you still do, then you have to prepare the runtime environment with the `gs` register properly initialized.

There is a syscall `arch_prctl()` (not wrapped by libc), which can be used to set the `gs` register:

```
arch_prctl(ARCH_SET_GS, baseaddr);
```

This could be a good start, but it has to be called, *before* the shadow call stack is populated (i.e. before `main()`). A good point is to initialize it in the `_start()` function, which is usually located in the unit `crt1.o` or similar.

Comment: Insecure?  Is it *worse* than just using the callstack for automatic storage?  (I'm somewhat curious about the design, but not enough to go digging through design documents or the code myself.  If you have any links to a useful summary of the design and/or what's wrong with it on x86-64, that'd be neat.)

Comment: @PeterCordes No, it is probably a bit better, but as I read between the lines it is not worth the performance penalty and may lead to a false sense of security. As for the design: Not more than the linked `Clang` documentation: At the top is a counter with the size of the shadow call stack, which gets incremented and decremented. The values are put and fetched from the offset there. Quite simple. When you are - as an attacker - able to write to arbitrary memory locations, it depends on the choice/randomness of the memory location how easy the exploitation is.

Comment: @PeterCordes I could not find a comprehensive evaluation how it is particularly insecure or inefficient.

Comment: @Ctx What should I put in baseaddr? The address of main()?

Comment: @lonelyBit No, the address of the shadow call stack (which has to be valid somehow).

Comment: @Ctx How can I get the address of shadow call stack? Is it specified in _start() function by myself? If yes, how can I verify if the address is valid? I'm a beginner in this field and sorry for cosuming your time.

Comment: @lonelyBit: from the return value of a big (like 8MiB) `malloc` or `mmap` to allocate space for this second stack.  Or just use static storage, like a big static `char` array that can go in the BSS.

Comment: @PeterCordes I failed with `linker command failed with exit code 1`. Does it mean the address is invalid? My code is: `char * addr = (char *) malloc(sizeof(char)*100);`

Comment: @lonelyBit: oh, are you trying to write your own `_start` in C?  It's not a function, you need some inline asm (or *very* dirty hacks).  And if you replace the CRT's `_start`, it's up to you to call `atexit` functions after `main` returns, and so on...    [How Get arguments value using inline assembly in C without Glibc?](//stackoverflow.com/q/50260855) shows how to write your own minimal `_start` which you can link *instead* of the normal CRT, using `-nostartfiles`.  Don't use this for anything but experimentation, and definitely not unless / until you're an asm expert.

Comment: The easiest is probably to disassemble crt1.o, put it in your own, custom mycrt1.S, add the commands to 1) allocate space for the callstack, 2) set the gs register accordingly, assemble it and use it instead of the default crt1.o. This is not an easy task, all in all!

Comment: @PeterCordes I checked again and found that once I use `arch_prctl` even if in a normal function Clang will throw `linker command failed with exit code 1`. I don't know why.

Comment: @lonelyBit As I said, the syscall is not wrapped by the libc, you have to use the syscall-macro or call it directly from asm.

Comment: @Ctx Do you have any guide or link about that?

Comment: https://gist.github.com/MerryMage/f22e75d5128c07d77630ca01c4272937 <- This  might give you an idea @lonelyBit

Comment: @lonelyBit: if your CPU supports [`wrgsbase`](https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/wrfsbase:wrgsbase) (I think since Broadwell or Skylake?), you can just use that instruction if the kernel enables it for use by user-space. But honestly, if you don't even know enough to post the actual linker error message about which symbol it couldn't find, instead of *failed with exit code 1* from some wrapper that ran it, let alone debug it yourself, writing your own `_start` to set GS base and then playing with clang's shadow stacks is probably out of reach until you get more experience with asm and tools.

Comment: "However, the shadow call stack feature is considered not only inefficient, but also insecure on x86_64 and it was removed in later versions" <-- do you have a citation for this? I don't doubt your claim but I would like to read about it.

Comment: @R.. See the latest version 10: https://clang.llvm.org/docs/ShadowCallStack.html (_An x86_64 implementation was evaluated using Chromium and was found to have critical performance and security deficiencies–it was removed in LLVM 9.0._). Unfortunately, no details on this evaluation can be found (at least not easily)

Comment: @R.. I have digged up this with some numbers, not much either, though: https://www.phoronix.com/scan.php?page=news_item&px=LLVM-Drops-ShadowCallStack-x64

Comment: This is a very old question, but the following works with clang 8 (the last version that supported shadow stack on x86_64) and Ubuntu 20.04: https://gist.github.com/moyix/f2e101348209ddeb7eba903147a867aa

Basically, it uses a constructor (which has to be excluded from the shadow stack instrumentation) to malloc some memory for the stack and then set gs.